# NIO2 and ByteBuffer use for reading variable length messages

Tags: java, io

I am reading variable length messages where each message is an int + msg bytes. Messages could be any size.

Right now my strategy is to have a direct buffer that reads from the socket, which then transfers the bytes read into an array-backed nondirect buffer. However my solution has a lot of copying, some loops and just feels a bit "icky".

Is there a better solution?

Here is the read completion handler. I'm hoping it should be pretty obvious what is going on:

```
class DelimitedReadCompletionHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Object> {

    private final AsynchronousByteChannel channel;
    private final Consumer<byte[]> onMessageCallback;
    private final ByteBuffer channelReadBuffer; // this is a direct buffer.

    private volatile ByteBuffer currentMessageBuffer;

    public DelimitedReadCompletionHandler(AsynchronousByteChannel channel,
                                          Consumer<byte[]> onMessageCallback,
                                          ByteBuffer channelReadBuffer) {

        this.channel = channel;
        this.onMessageCallback = onMessageCallback;
        this.channelReadBuffer = channelReadBuffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void completed(Integer result,
                          Object attachment) {

        channelReadBuffer.flip();

        do {
            if (currentMessageBuffer == null) {
                if (channelReadBuffer.remaining() < Integer.BYTES) {
                    channelReadBuffer.compact();
                    break;
                }

                currentMessageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(channelReadBuffer.getInt());
            }

            int copyLength = Integer.min(currentMessageBuffer.remaining(), channelReadBuffer.remaining());

            for (int i = 0; i < copyLength; i++) {
                currentMessageBuffer.put(channelReadBuffer.get());
            }

            if (!currentMessageBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                byte[] msg = currentMessageBuffer.array();
                ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> onMessageCallback.accept(msg));

                currentMessageBuffer = null;
            }

            if (channelReadBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                continue;
            }

            channelReadBuffer.clear();
            break;
        } while (true);

        channel.read(channelReadBuffer, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable exc,
                       Object attachment) {

        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write some JavaDoc!

As stated above, I was very confused by your code. However, if your methods included JavaDoc, then I wouldn't be so confused by the names.

Here is an example of JavaDoc on a simple method:

```
/**
    Returns the sum of both of the parameters.
*/
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

*Note the `/**`? This is required for it to be valid JavaDoc.*

In more complicated functions where the parameters aren't clear or the return value isn't clear, you can include something like this in your JavaDoc:

```
@param nameOfParameter -- description/purpose of parameter
@return -- description of return
        -- description of return
        -- description of return
```

*You would have multiple `-- description of return`s if there were multiple potential return values.*

---

There is no point in having a `do/while` loop where the condition being checked is `true`; if it were just a normal `while` loop, it would run atleast once anyway.

I recommend that you change your `do/while` to just a `while` as `while` loops are much more common.

---

I can not go into the way you tried to solve the problem because I am having trouble understanding your code. I believe this is just on me, but I think that having more documentation would help anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you realise or not, but `CompletionHandler` is part of the JDK! I am implementing this interface so have no choice but to use those method names. Also the JavaDoc that is on the interface is sufficient I feel (not sure what other people feel). Agree about the do-while loop, i guess I was just being lazy by writing less code.

Comment: You are right; I didn't even notice `CompletionHandler` was part of the JDK.